# Understanding the code snippet in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have taken the code snippet from Rails GUides Book . What I am unable to understand is that how come  articles_path redirect the page to two different pages. In first case it is redirecting to articles/5 and in second case it is redirecting to articles. How is this parameter changing the redirection url

```
<%= form_for :article ,url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following case

```
<%= form_for :article ,url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

Its a http `POST` to articles_path

In

```
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Its a http `GET`

so http verb determines the action in this case.
When you do `rake routes`, you will see the following

```
articles GET /articles(.:format)     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
         POST /articles(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. . I want to know is this rake routes predefined , what if I want to change the predefined path of get and post verb to something else

Comment: rake routes' output is based directly on routes.rb.  If you want to specify routes there, you normally use `resources` which handles defaults for the 7 RESTful endpoints.  Otherwise, you can use helpers like `get 'exit', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :logout` to do custom routing.